# Groovy split with RegEx get string between 2 other strings

Tags: java, groovy

I have a question, i also searched a long time to get the answer. But nothing was working for me. I hope someone can help me please.

I hava a very long String like this:

```
"... {"test":"test","name":"version1","archived":false,"released":false,"projectId":xx5},{"test":"test","name":"fix1","archived":false,"released":false,"projectId":xx5},  ..."
```

now i want to get all values after "name". In this little example it is then "version1" and "fix1". I try to do this with regex. But it seems that i am doing something wrong. 
Programming language is GROOVY.

```
def raiseStarList = []
def regex = '(?<="name":")*(?=",")'
for (String s : response.split(regex)) {
    if ( s.contains("Raise") ) {
        raiseStarList << s
    }
}
println raiseStarList
```

As you can see i try to filter between "name":" and ","

But my RegEx is not working correctly.

Comment: This looks like a JSON string. Why not do JSON parsing and simplify your life?

Comment: Yes you are right. That makes it simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def s='''[{"test":"test","name":"version1","archived":false,"released":false,"projectId":"xx5"},{"test":"test","name":"fix1","archived":false,"released":false,"projectId":"xx5"}]'''

//using json parser
def j = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(s)
def res = j.collect{it.name}
println res

//using regex
def r = /"name":"([^"]*)"/
def res2=(s=~r).collect{it[1]}
println res2
```